# Linked List Error-Infinite Loop

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am constructing a simple `linked list` with the `display()` and `add_at_end()` function. Following is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node{
    int num;
    struct node *next;

}n;
n* head;
class ll{
public:
ll();
~ll();

void display();
void add_at_end(int n);
//void add_at_beginning(int n);
//int count();
//void delete_num(int n);
};
ll::ll(){

    head=NULL;
}
ll::~ll(){
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        n *temp;
        while(head!=NULL)
        {
            temp=head->next;
            delete head;
            head=temp;
        }
    }

}

void ll::display(){
if(head==NULL)
    cout<<"There is nothing to display in the list";
else
{
    n *temp;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
        {cout<<temp->num;}
}}
void ll::add_at_end(int number)
{
    n *temp=new n;
    temp->num=number;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
        head=temp;
    else
    {

        n *tmp2;
        tmp2=head;
        while(tmp2!=NULL)
        {   tmp2=tmp2->next;}
        tmp2=temp;
    }

}
        int main(){
        ll* fll=new ll();
        fll->add_at_end(54);
        fll->display();
    return 0;
}
```

Everything else is fine but when I run the code, I get an infinite loop where 54 keeps getting printed again and again. Where am I making a mistake? In the `display()` function or the `add_at_end()` function?

Comment: You might want to look closer at that loop in your `add_at_end` function.

Comment: Other than that, I recommend you step through the code, line by line, in a debugger. This might help you narrow the problem down to a specific function, and maybe figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite loop happens in the display.  You did not advance the temp pointer

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake

In the `display()` function while loop I was not increment `temp` variable. So I changed the code to

```
while(temp!=NULL)
        {cout<<temp->num;
        temp=temp->next;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should also fix your add_at_end function:

```
    while(tmp2->next != NULL)
    {
        tmp2 = tmp2->next; 
    }

    tmp2->next = temp;
```